# Python pandas drop_duplicates with rolling window

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame (about 500,000 rows) with a datetime index and 3 columns (a, b, c):

```
                           a       b        c
2016-03-30 09:59:36.619    0       55       0
2016-03-30 09:59:41.979    0       20       0
2016-03-30 09:59:41.986    0       1        0
2016-03-30 09:59:45.853    0       1        3
2016-03-30 09:59:51.265    0       20       9
2016-03-30 10:00:03.273    0       55       26
2016-03-30 10:00:05.658    0       55       28
2016-03-30 10:00:17.416    0       156      0
2016-03-30 10:00:17.928    0       122      1073
2016-03-30 10:00:21.933    0       122      0
2016-03-30 10:00:31.937    0       122      10
2016-03-30 10:00:40.941    0       122      0
2016-03-30 10:00:51.147    10      2        0
2016-03-30 10:01:27.060    0       156      0
```

I want to search within a 10 minute rolling window and remove duplicate items from one of the columns (column b), to get something like this:

```
                           a       b        c
2016-03-30 09:59:36.619    0       55       0
2016-03-30 09:59:41.979    0       20       0
2016-03-30 09:59:41.986    0       1        0
2016-03-30 09:59:51.265    0       20       9
2016-03-30 10:00:03.273    0       55       26
2016-03-30 10:00:17.416    0       156      0
2016-03-30 10:00:17.928    0       122      1073
2016-03-30 10:00:51.147    10      2        0
2016-03-30 10:01:27.060    0       156      0
```

Using `drop_duplicates` with `rolling_apply` comes to mind, but these two functions don't play well together, i.e.:

```
pd.rolling_apply(df, '10T', lambda x:x.drop_duplicates(subset='b'))
```

raises an error, since the function must return a value, not a df.
So this is what I have so far:

```
import datetime as dt
windows = []
for ind in range(len(df)):
    t0 = df.index[ind]
    t1 = df.index[ind]+dt.timedelta(minutes=10)

    windows.append(df[numpy.logical_and(t0<df.index,\
    df.index<=t1)].drop_duplicates(subset='b'))
```

Here I end up with a list of 10 min dataframes with duplicates removed, but there are a lot of overlapping values as the window rolls on to the next 10 min segment.  To keep the unique values, I've tried something like:

```
new_df = []
for ind in range(len(windows)-1):
    new_df.append(pd.unique(pd.concat([pd.Series(windows[ind].index),\
    pd.Series(windows[ind+1].index)])))
```

But this doesn't work, and it's already starting to get messy. Does anyone have any bright ideas how to solve this as efficiently as possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is useful. I roll a function that checks if the last value is a duplicate of an earlier element over a 10 minute window. The result can be used with boolean indexing.

```
# Simple example
dates = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods = 5, freq = '4min')
col1 = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':col1}, index = dates)

# Make function that checks if last element is a duplicate
def last_is_duplicate(a):
    if len(a) > 1:
        return a[-1] in a[:len(a)-1]
    else: 
        return False    

# Roll over 10 minute window to find duplicates of recent elements
dup = df.col1.rolling('10T').apply(last_is_duplicate).astype('bool')

# Keep only those rows for which col1 is not a recent duplicate
df[~dup]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice approach.

Comment: how can this be transformed into multiple columns? Because you're using `df.col1.rolling`

I want to check if there's a duplicate transaction based upon two columns in a 2 min window.

Also, is it necessary that the index should be time-based?

Comment: can you please have a look 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285964/how-to-find-duplicate-based-upon-multiple-columns-in-a-rolling-window-in-pandas

Comment: Does concatenating the columns first solve your problem?

Comment: no! I tried, it doesn't. because one of the two columns is string and it gives two errors. One fail to convert to float. Second rolling isn't allowed on string type.